# Put an xcoffin around an environment's content

Tags: environments, xcoffins

I'm trying to use xcoffins as a lightweight tcolorbox, like so:

[image: demo]

This works great when defining a command I can wrap content in, however I **need** to make this behaviour accessible through an environment, i.e. instead of `\test{hi}`,

```
\begin{test}
hi
\end{test}
```

I am aware of the environ package, but would like to keep things as lightweight as possible. I'm hoping someone might know how this could be achieved with xcoffins, or plain LaTeX.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin\Content
\NewCoffin\SideRule

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \SetVerticalCoffin\Content{\linewidth}{\noindent#1}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\SideRule{\color{blue!70!green!70!black}\rule{1pt}{\CoffinTotalHeight\Content}}

  \JoinCoffins*\Content[l,t]\SideRule[l,t](-0.5em,0pt)
  \noindent\TypesetCoffin\Content
  \vspace*{\CoffinTotalHeight\Content}\bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\test{Hey\\there}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\vcoffin_set:Nnw` from the programming layer `l3coffins` (`xcoffins` is just a thin wrapper around `l3coffins`).  `\SetVerticalCoffin` just provides access to `\vcoffin_set:Nnn` (note the `n` at the end) which means the contents have to be grabbed as an argument.  The `:Nnw` version is precisely to be used in situations like this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin\Content
\NewCoffin\SideRule

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {test} { }
  {
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \Content { \linewidth }
      \noindent \ignorespaces
  }
  {
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\SideRule{\color{blue!70!green!70!black}\rule{1pt}{\CoffinTotalHeight\Content}}

    \JoinCoffins*\Content[l,t]\SideRule[l,t](-0.5em,0pt)
    \noindent\TypesetCoffin\Content
    \vspace*{\CoffinTotalHeight\Content}\bigskip
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Hey\\there
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

You could also use `\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { b }`, to grab the body of the environment (that's built into LaTeX, so no packages needed), but I think `\vcoffin_set:Nnw` is a much better option here.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Many thanks.